# Updating controller variable upon ng-option being selected

Tags: angularjs

I am currently trying to set a variable in a controller upon another value being selected via `ng-options`. For example, if one selected from `Companies` according to `title` then `myValue` will be set to the corresponding `id` of a specific company. The following is the HTML snippet:

```
<select multiple="" class="form-control" ng-model="myValue" 
          ng-options="d.title for d in Companies"></select>


<select multiple="" class="form-control">
<option ng-placeholder="{{myValue}}"></option>
</select>
```

And my `Company`,`Companies`, and `myValue` in the controller:

```
function Company(title, last, pw, id) {
    this.title = title;
    this.id = id;
}
$scope.Companies = [];

$scope.myValue = '';
```

And here is the fucntion that seeds the `Companies` array:

```
$scope.getValues = function () {
    $http.get('/route/to/names')
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $scope.Companies.push(new Company(data[i]['Title'],data[i]['ID']));
        }
    })
};
```

The purpose behind the program is to further fetch data from a database according to the selected `Company`. The reason why I have `myValue` set as an option on the page is to determine if the action is achieved. Any advice as to how to solve this or similar problems would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `d.id as d.title for d in Companies` - Make sure to use the correct casing, as you have `title` and `id` lower-case in your Company constructor but proper cased in your for loop.

Comment: Am I missing some sort of `ActionEvent` which would trigger the initialization of `myVal`? Or is the mere selection of an option enough for databinding to occur given my program? Oh and it is uppercase because it is accessing specific properties `'Title'` and `'ID'` of an object.

Comment: Well you have your model bound to an empty string so I'm assuming your select inserts an option at the start which is not a id. It will be be bound by being present on your select. You could not even have it in your controller and when you made a selection it would be added to scope.

Comment: Also, your comment was indeed correct, so thank you, KreepN.

Comment: Added it as an answer for you, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d.id as d.title for d in Companies
```

- Make sure to use the correct casing, as you have title and id lower-case in your Company constructor but proper cased in your for loop